# Terminal "breaks"?

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I came across an unusual situation while writing this C++ program in Ubuntu.

The program:

```
#inclue <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void sizeOfTest() {
  int i = 27;
  unsigned int u = 14;
  float f = 3.14;
  double d = 2.71;
  char c ='c';
  bool b = true;
  int* n = &i;
  char* h = &c;
  double* o = &d;
  cout << "The size of int " << i << " is " << sizeof(i) << ".\n";
  cout << "The size of unsigned int " << u << " is " << sizeof(u) << ".\n";
  cout << "The size of float " << f << " is " << sizeof(f) << ".\n";
  cout << "The size of double " << d << " is " << sizeof(d) << ".\n";
  cout << "The size of char " << c << " is " << sizeof(c) << ".\n";
  cout << "The size of bool " << b << " is " << sizeof(b) << ".\n";
  cout << "The size of int* " << n << " is " << sizeof(n) << ".\n";
  cout << "The size of char* " << h << " is " << sizeof(h) << ".\n";
  cout << "The size of double* " << o << " is " << sizeof(o) << ".\n";
}

void outputBinary(unsigned int n) {
  string s = "";
  while (n != 0 || s. length() != 32) {
    if (n%2 == 1) {
      s = "1" + s;
      n = (n-1)/2;
    }
    else {
      s = "0" + s;
      n = n/2;
    }
  }
  cout << s.substr(0,4) << " " << s.substr(4,4) << " " << s.substr(8,4) << " " << s.substr(12,4) << " " << s.substr(16,4) << " " << s.substr(20,4) << " " << s.substr(24,4) << " " << s.substr(28,4) << " ";
}

void overflow() {
  unsigned int m = 65535;
  cout << (m+1);
}

int main() {
  unsigned int x;
  cout << "Please enter an integer:";
  cin >> x;
  sizeOfTest();
  outputBinary(x);
  overflow();
  return 0;
}
```

The output:
[image]

So my questions are:

1. Why are my newlines not working? (They are all in the exact same format as the `cout` line in the `sizeOfTest` function.)
2. What happened when I called `h` that caused all the following characters to break, even when outside the `a.out` file? And how do I fix this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Quick thing that'll make it easier for you to keep working: if you get back to the prompt and the terminal is still garbage, use the command "reset" to make it usable again.

Comment: Please put complete code. It will help to analyse.

Comment: @user1861447 - done. I refrained at first because based on my experience, people seemed to prefer not having to read code that isn't relevant to the problem.

Comment: 2012ssohn, that code did not produce that output. You need to check again.

Comment: Terminals can be reconfigured by sending them special commands; probably the garbage contained a "change font" or "change character set" command by random chance.

Comment: @paxdiablo - whoops, I copied and pasted the sizeof h line and forgot to change the variable inside sizeof for each line... it's fixed now.

Comment: 2012ssohn, that code does not even *compile* (dodgy include and invalid definition of `u`), please cut and paste the *real* code, anything else is a waste of time.

Comment: @paxdiablo - I understand that the space bar between 'int' and 'u' did not get transferred through for some reason, but if you're so lazy that you can't be bothered to insert that space and recompile, I don't want your help anyway.

Comment: I *did* insert the space (and the d in include). It compiled and ran fine. It's actually *your* laziness I'd be more concerned with, especially since *you're* the one seeking assistance. The reason I'm saying it's a waste of time is because small errors like that don't tend to occur when you've cut and pasted the code with something like CTRL-C/V, they're indicative of someone retyping, as was you pre-edit statement that you cut and pasted the lines all using `sizeof(h)` *despite* the fact you seemed to have run totally different code in your screen dump.

Comment: As to your comment you don't want my help, that's fine too, I'll move on. There are people I can help here who are not so prone to be thin-skinned and are more than willing to assist *themselves* in the process rather than just sit around and wait for the answer on a platter. Good luck...

Comment: Yes I did retype the code completely to post it here - my Ubuntu computer displays everything in the browser far too small for me to see anything, and my Windows computer cannot run Ubuntu. Thus I had to retype everything in the Ubuntu computer into the Windows computer. I'm sorry I made a few transcription mistakes, but that is no reason for you to lash out at me like that, especially since you were unaware of my situation. And I did resolve the problem thanks to people like sfjac, and there are plenty of nicer people out there who won't look down on people who are trying to learn. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `ostream` inserters assume that a `char *` argument will point to a null terminated string. That is not the case here. So it will write junk from memory until it comes across a `0x0` character in memory.

If you just want to print the address of `c`, then cast `h` to `void *`:

```
cout << "The size of the address " << (void *)h << " is " << sizeof(h) << "." << endl;
```

Regarding the newlines, you might try replacing `"\n"` with `std::endl`. I don't think you said what terminal or OS you're on, but its possible that there is confusion in the terminal over the meaning of "\n". (Shouldn't be, but if this is gcc on Windows in cygwin or something, who knows.)

Comment: So is there a way to print `h`, a pointer to a `char`, and then make the terminal resume printing as normal?

Comment: Are you just wanting to print the address of `c`?